# How to animate child control from a parent control in a style?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to animate an image inside of the button. However, after attempts and many errors later I can't seem to figure it out on my own.

I've found several threads that got close to a solution for me, such as this thread, which is similar to what I'm doing:
[How to affect child control properties from a style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127740/how-to-affect-child-control-properties-from-a-style)

But, I'm trying to animate the image.

This is my xaml design:

```
<Button Name="dbButton" Style="{StaticResource imgButton}" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Click="DatabaseButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="300,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ToolTip="View Database">
        <Image Source="{StaticResource img_database}" Height="100" Width="100"/>
</Button>
```

And this is the style I'm trying to build:

```
<Style x:Key="imgButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <!--start of image child style-->
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ScaleTransform 
                        x:Name="imgScale" 
                        CenterX="50" 
                        CenterY="50" 
                        ScaleX="1" 
                        ScaleY="1"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <!--end of image child style-->
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate x:Name="tmpltButton">
                <Grid>                        
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContent" 
                                      Opacity=".7" 
                                      Content="{Binding Path=Content, 
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="center" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="center">
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseLeave">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOut}"/>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverIn}"/>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.LostFocus">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOut}"/>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.GotFocus">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverIn}"/>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
```

This is the HoverIn and HoverOut animations:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="HoverOut" Duration="00:00:00.250">
    <DoubleAnimation 
        BeginTime="00:00:00"
        To="1" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="imgScale"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"/>
    <DoubleAnimation 
        BeginTime="00:00:00"
        To="1" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="imgScale" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"/>
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Key="HoverIn" Duration="00:00:00.250">
    <DoubleAnimation 
        BeginTime="00:00:00" 
        To="1.5" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="imgScale" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"/>
    <DoubleAnimation 
        BeginTime="00:00:00" 
        To="1.5" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="imgScale" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"/>
</Storyboard>
```

I was following along with this resource for learning styles:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85896/WPF-Customize-your-Application-with-Styles-and-C

Comment: Surely this is possible.. Did I give enough information in my post?